# How to recursively calculate tree depth in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I currently have a table in SQLite that looks something like the following, forming a tree-like structure:

```
+-----+-----------+---------------+
| _id | parent_id | tree_depth    |
+=====+===========+===============+
| 1   | 0         | 0             |
| 2   | 1         | (should be 1) |
| 3   | 2         | (should be 2) |
+-----+-----------+---------------+
```

I have very limited SQLite experience and the table is quite large, so I would hate to have to fill it out manually. Is there a query I could use to update the tree_depth column such that it properly represents the depth of the tree at that node? I tried selecting the parent's tree depth and incrementing, but for some reason it set everything to 1.

Any advise would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: The query that I'm trying is:

```
UPDATE table SET tree_depth = (SELECT p.tree_depth FROM table JOIN table p ON p._id=table.parent_id) +1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a [recursive CTE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html#recursivecte) to compute the tree depth of each entry.
You can then use this data to look up the value to UPDATE:

```
WITH RECURSIVE depths(id, depth) AS (
    SELECT _id, 0
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE parent_id = 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT MyTable._id, depths.depth + 1
    FROM MyTable
    JOIN depths ON MyTable.parent_id = depths.id
)
UPDATE MyTable
SET tree_depth = (SELECT depth
                  FROM depths
                  WHERE depths.id = MyTable._id);
```

(Note: older Android versions do not support CTEs.)

Answer (score -1):

Please try?

```
update table
set a.tree_depth = b.parent_id
```

If it doesn't wok, try to add this too:

```
FROM table a 
INNER JOIN table b
on a._id= b._id
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work as SQLite doesn't allow FROM in UPDATE. Also, a.tree_depth should be b.tree_depth + 1. However, I can't get it to JOIN properly.